# How can I use a JSON API in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to write a local application in JavaScript to fetch some JSON data from a site, parse it, and display some statistics for me.  So far I have been unable to get it to work, or even able to pull JSON from any site anywhere.  Is this because of the same origin policy?  I thought this would be relaxed for a locally stored .html file on my own machine.

The site I am trying to use doesn't appear to support JSONP or CORS.

I would have thought this was a common scenario and am surprised that I can't get it to work, although I'm not very experienced with JavaScript.  I tried using XMLHttpRequest, and I also taught myself quite a bit of JQuery, but I am unable to get any simple access to work.

Is what I am trying to do impossible?

In JQuery, my basic access looks like this - the alert popup never gets called.

```
$.getJSON(url,function(result) {
  alert("success");
});
```

Comment: Are there any error messages showing up on your browser console? IIRC chrome logs the reason for an ajax failure

Comment: can u fetch url from ur  browser then JS will .... JSON is JavaScriptObjNotn so JavaScript will be always in favour....

Comment: Are you writing a location application or a web application that you will run in the browser. Because if you're just writing a program locally, you don't need it to execute in the browser. You can use nodejs and all of its libraries to request remote files. Even if you need it to run in the browser, you can still get it to tell the server-side nodejs (or any other server-side platform) to request the remote file.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought this would be relaxed for a locally stored .html file on my own machine.

No, the opposite is usually true – local files usually can’t even request other local files via Ajax.

Anyways, yes, it is probably because of the same origin policy. For a local thing, what you can do is proxy the page you need through some server in some language and also use that server to serve your files. Nginx can, in fact, do that all on its own; the configuration would look something like the below. You could also use `curl` and CGI.

```
location = /proxymypage {
    proxy_pass http://remote-site.com/data.json;
}

location / {
    root /path/to/your/files;
}
```